# Execute logic inside RxJS pipe with unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Trying to initialize the variable x inside the pipe() method when doing unit testing, but it does not get called. How do I run method calls/initialization logic inside pipe()? Simply calling `component.ngOnInit()` inside the unit test does not help.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.foo$ = this.myService.bar$.pipe(
      ....
      map(bar => {
        this.x = bar.x;        // how do I call this within unit test 
        return bar;
      })
    );  
}

it('should init x', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.x).toEqual(bar.x); //fails
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to subscribe and then tick

```
  import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing'; 

  it('should init x', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    component.foo$.subscribe();
    tick();
    expect(component.x).toEqual(bar.x); 
  }));
```

Comment: Tried that but it just skips the code inside .pipe().